# Service or tool for storing all IM chat

Tags: chat, web-application

I normally use different IM applications (Pidgin, Digsby, MSN etc.) on several computers. Is there some tool or web application for storing the chat logs online and that allows searching through them?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that makes knowing a scripting language like Python or Perl useful, they could merge the logs into a common format and search through them fairly easily.

Comment: why do you want to store them online?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Simkl history saver](http://simkl.com/) or [G-Recorder](http://g-recorder.com/usage.htm)(Skype only) service. There also was [IM-History](http://www.im-history.com/) service around, but unfortunately registration is not possible for quite a while.

In case you don't care of online history search but synchronization is a must, you should consider setting up free homebrewed solution based on [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) service, for example. Refer to this [post](http://raanan.com/2009/06/22/sync-skype-on-multiple-machines-with-dropbox/) for more details.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the only purpose is to search through them, maybe you'd like [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). There are variants available for Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is point the logging folders, instead of to the programs' default locations, to an online storage drive mounted to your Z: drive which is setup on all of your computers.

I don't personally use online storage yet so encourage you to do some research of your own.  I've heard mozy is good and dropbox is an old trusted name that somehow seems to be missing from the 'top 10' list which pops up from:
http://www.google.com/search?q=online+storage+comparison

How to change Digsby log location:
http://forum.digsby.com/viewtopic.php?pid=14847#p14847

Pidgin:
http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#Wherearemysettingsanddataincludinglogssaved

MSN:
http://www.google.com/search?&q=MSN+messenger+%22Save+my+conversations+in+this+folder%22

Answer (score 0):

combine them all into one html file with softsnow merger then search through that file. You can use a web browser it is in 1 file.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall everything and use Meebo instead.

Comment: -1 and no comment ? Dear coward, please explain.